Include an image inside as though it's a letter inside a <text> span on svg
I'd really like to place an image at a specific place within some text in an svg:
 <text>The <image href="cow.png" width="5px" height="5px"/> jumped over the moon </text>
Or something to the effect, It's really hard to calculate exactly where I need the cow.
Is there a way to place it inside text? so that it takes up the right amount of space?
I've tried putting the element inside the text, but the text just seems to ignore it.

I guess you'd need to create a font that contained an image as a letter. Maybe you can do that with SVG in opentype fonts: https://robert.ocallahan.org/2013/02/svg-in-opentype-new-approach-to-svg.html

Or use foreignObject because this kind of thing is much easier in HTML.

If your ultimate goal is to get a self-contained SVG image asset (e.g abutton) you're better off doing the layout in a GUI driven graphic application such as inkscape, Illustrator etc. SVG won't automatically embed fonts or image references in your file (however graphic apps usually provide options for this – adding base64 encoded data-URLs). All in all, SVG's tspan and it's text composing capabilities are not remotely on par with HTML/CSS  – you can't nest non-text elements in <text>. You could also convert a vector image to an icon font with tools like fontello or icomoon
